# What's wrong when i transfer the java code to iOS code about connecting to the server and get result?

Tags: java, ios, post, request, nsmutableurlrequest

The java code is below,It's about to connect to the server and get some information, you can run the java code and get {"carrier":{"CFeeC":1,"COrderC":1,"CTaskC":1,"flag":1},"driver":{"DTaskC":1,"DTraceR":1,"flag":1},"userinfo":{"czBizOrgId":"30500002049","czWebOrgId":545587,"hzBizOrgId":"30500000857","hzWebOrgId":545593,"userEmail":"all@1.com","userId":545566,"userName":"all all all"},"return_code":"00","customer":{"flag":1,"hFeeC":1,"hOrderA":1,"hOrderC":1,"hOrderS":1,"hPlanM":1,"hPlanS":1}}null

but when i run iOS code blew the java code,answer is {"exception":"Authenticated access required"} it seems that tha parameter that i send ,the server didn't get?why?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(test());
}

private static String test() {
    String username = "all@1.com";
    String password = "1";

        String path = new String("http://61.174.31.28:9091/api/jsonws/UnicomWL-portlet.tcdcolligate/user-login/password/1/email/all%401.com"); // ƴ�����URL��ַ
        //path = path.replace("+","%20");

    try {
        String authString =username + ":" +password;
        String authStringEnc = new String(Base64.encode(authString.getBytes()));
        URL url = new URL(path);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);

        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                connection.getOutputStream());

        bufferedOutputStream.flush();
        bufferedOutputStream.close();

        if (connection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("ResponseCode != 200");
        }
        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(
                connection.getInputStream());
        int bytesRead = 0;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        while ((bytesRead = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {


            String chunk = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            System.out.print(chunk);
        }
        connection.disconnect();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }


    return  null;
```

but when i tried used iOS ,it's wrong ,what's the matter? thank you

```
    int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {
    // insert code here...
    NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

    NSData *authData=[@"all@1.com:1" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *authStringEnc=[authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    NSString *auth=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic +%@",authStringEnc];
    NSLog(@"%@\n",auth);

    NSString *path=@"http://61.174.31.28:9091/api/jsonws/UnicomWL-portlet.tcdcolligate/user-login/password/1/email/all%401.com";

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:path];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    NSData *returnData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *s=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",s);

}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", @"username", @"password"];
NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64Encoding]];
[request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Here is a sample project that worked. [sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vrluaekubdl17p8/ConnectToServer.zip?dl=0)

Comment: thank you , I know what's going on .@"Basic +%@"should be @"Basic %@"